# Spring Boot Multitenancy

Tags: hibernate, dynamic, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

We have a spring boot application using hibernates multi tenancy. We've used an implementation similar to the one used in this blog ---
http://www.ticnfae.co.uk/blog/2014/07/16/hibernate-multi-tenancy-with-spring/

The issue now is when we try to change the tenant for multiple parallel scheduled task using the code snippet below tenants get all mixed. How can this issue be reolved

```
     SessionFactory hibernateFactory = getSessionFactory(emf);

    ((CurrentTenantIdentifierRslvr)((SessionFactoryImpl) 
                 hibernateFactory)
               .getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver())
               ._tenantIdentifier.set("somedbname");
```